# Login system connecting with database in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a login system, connecting to a database in a spreadsheet.
I've tried all the ways, but in all I haven't been successful.

The system is simple, it takes the data from the form and searches the spreadsheet if the email exists, if it exists it logs in.

Can someone help me?

Follows Html code:

```js
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet')

{ promisify } = require('util');

const credentials = require('../credentials.json')

async function loginBase(){
    
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(credentials);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[7];
    const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)();
    var controle = false;

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
      
        if(rows[i].email == mail){
            alert("Login realizado com sucesso");
            //console.log("Usuário válidado com sucesso")
            //location: "./dashboard.html"
            //controle = true;
            window.location.href = "http://www.devmedia.com.br";
            //return true;

        }
    }
    
    if(controle == false){
        //alert('Usuário não encontrado');
        //console.log("Usuário não encontrado");  
        alert("Usuário inválido");
        //return false;
    }
    

}

Follows JS code:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Holding Grupo Five</title>  
    
</head>
<body>
   <div class="login">
       <div class="login-form">
        <div class="login-form-wrapper">
            <form id="formLogin">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail.">                  
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="senha" class="form-label">Senha</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha.">
                </div>   
                <script src="js/login.js"></script>                  
                <button onclick="loginBase()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>                
              </form>  
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="banner-login">            
            <img src="imagens/LogoGrupoPreto.png" alt="Grupo Five">         
       </div>

   </div>

   <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="plugins/fontawesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I thought that your script is for Node.js. But your tags are `javascript`, `html` and `google-apps-script`. Is your goal to use Google Apps Script?

Comment: Yes, my script is accessing a Google Spreadsheet spreadsheet, and there is a list of allowed users, so it reads this database and returns if the user has permission.

Comment: you have the condition `if(rows[i].email == mail)` in your for loop. But `mail` does not appear to be defined above. Is that a typo? Also isn't a row an array? In your for loop you are checking `rows[i].email` which implies that `rows[i]` is an object and `email` is a property on that object.